# Unix timestamp in Drupal 8 Views

Tags: date, twig, drupal-8

I want to make reports in Views Drupal 8 using a content type with two date fields.
The report shall calculate the difference between two date fields (field_start and field_end). Planning to do this with Twig in a global custom text field in Views. I thought I could use Unix timestamp. Have found {{ 'now'|date('U') }} that produce the timestamp for now, but I do not found how to convert a drupal date field to Unix timestamp so I can calculate the difference between the two fields field_start and end_field.

Comment: Just do the same, `{{ your_var | date('d-m-Y') }}`

Comment: What I can see this result in Twig_Error_Runtime when I using it in Global custom text field

Comment: Another approach could be to use the 'U* format on the two fields. This generates two values representing seconds that I could use to do the needed operations on. The problem is that it comes in string format and I do not find the way to convert it to an integer with Twig.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was (thanks, Denis) to set the output format for the two fields field_start and field_end to 'U'. This makes the field's output to an amount of seconds. In the Custom text field I calculate the difference with this:
{%set seconds=field_gick.__tostring()-field_kom.__tostring()%}
{{seconds}}